# Impact of pure white on color histogram

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, histogram

I am trying to use KNN method to classify people into races based on their face photos. I have a dataset of faces on a pure white background [255, 255, 255].

As a feed input, I am using values of a color histogram. I was told I should remove the background color from the histogram to improve the performance of KNN.

Problem: When I create a mask from my photo that ignores background, histogram does not change one tiny bit.

Question: I am not so really into the theory of colors, does pure white color have an impact on the shape of color histogram at all? When I use regular mask that only centers(as on image below) the histogram changes.

[image: Constructed mask - no change to histogram]

This is the mask I constructed from the picture, ignoring background

[image: Simple mask - changes histogram]

Simple mask to test the correctness of mask application

[image: Original image]

Source image for a histogram counting

[image: Original and constructed mask histogram]
This is the histogram I get from picture without any mask and from my constructed mask ignoring white color as well.

[image: Simple mask histogram]
This is histogram I get from cropping picture using my simple mask. histogram changes, I therefore suppose my method for counting histogram is correct.

Code for counting histogram:

```
# loop over the image channels
for (chan, color) in zip(channels, colors):
    # create a histogram for the current channel and
    # concatenate the resulting histograms for each channel
    hist_full = opencv.calcHist([chan], [0], mask, [bin_amount], [0, bin_amount])

    # plot the histogram
    plt.plot(hist_full, color=color)
    plt.xlim([0, bin_amount])

plt.show()
```

Code for creating mask:

```
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)
    # simple mask option
    # mask[75:175, 75:175] = 255


    # create a mask to ignore white background in the histogram
    for row in range(0, len(image)):

        for col in range(0, len(image[0])):

            if (image[row][col] != np.asarray(prop.background)).all():
                try:
                    mask[row][col] = 255
                except IndexError:
                    print(col)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Important part:

> Python: cv2.calcHist(images, channels, mask, histSize, ranges[, hist[, accumulate]]) → hist
>
> Parameters: ...
> ranges – Array of the dims arrays of the histogram bin boundaries in each dimension. When the histogram is uniform ( uniform =true), then for each dimension i it is enough to specify the lower (inclusive) boundary  L_0 of the 0-th histogram bin and the upper (exclusive) boundary  U_{\texttt{histSize}[i]-1} for the last histogram bin histSize[i]-1 .

Try to change this part of your code

```
hist_full = opencv.calcHist([chan], [0], mask, [bin_amount], [0, bin_amount])
```

as follows

```
hist_full = opencv.calcHist([chan], [0], mask, [bin_amount], [0, 256])
```

You need to specify range of real values in the picture (upper boundary exclusive).
Most probably, now you count only values 0-63 and ignore 64-255 in your histogram.